# Promise resolve will not fire

Tags: javascript, promise, ecmascript-6

I'm wondering why this will not log out the resolve `.then` method. The idea is to log out every failure, then as soon as the values match, log out the "Winner Winner" that is in the `.then` method.

```js
var winner = 5;
var ticket = 0;
var roll = function() {
  ticket = Math.round(Math.random() * 10);
}
var play = function() {
  roll();
  return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
    if (ticket === winner) {
      resolve();
    } else {
      console.log("Sorry Try Again");
      play();
    }
  });

}


play().then(function() {
  console.log("Winner Winner!")
});
```

Comment: you don't have a `.then()` callback on the inner call to `play()`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're only logging the winner when the first `play()` succeeds, not the recursive ones. Add a `.then()` to the inner call.

```js
var winner = 5;
var ticket = 0;
var roll = function() {
  ticket = Math.round(Math.random() * 10);
}
var play = function() {
  roll();
  return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
    if (ticket === winner) {
      resolve();
    } else {
      console.log("Sorry Try Again");
      play().then(function() {
        console.log("Winner Winner");
      });
    }
  });

}


play().then(function() {
  console.log("Winner Winner!")
});
```

If you don't want to repeat that code in both places, define a function that does it.

```js
var winner = 5;
var ticket = 0;
var roll = function() {
  ticket = Math.round(Math.random() * 10);
}
var play = function() {
  roll();
  return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
    if (ticket === winner) {
      resolve();
    } else {
      console.log("Sorry Try Again");
      playtest();
    }
  });

}

function playtest() {
  play().then(function() {
    console.log("Winner Winner!")
  });
}

playtest();
```

Comment: Huh, this is so strange. I assumed the play function would run the same even if recursive. But now that I'm looking at it, it makes more sense. Thank you for the fast and easy answer!

Comment: @JaromandaX Could you post an answer showing the better structure, and explaining how it works? I'm not an expert on ES6 promises, so I wouldn't be able to do it justice.

Comment: Nevermind - both my suggestion and your solutions are vulnerable to `too much recursion` - try the code with random*1000 and you'll see

Answer (score 1):

If you want to avoid `too much recursion` - which can happen even with such a small random range, you could do this

```
var retry = function retry(fn) {
  return fn().catch(function () {
    return retry(fn);
  });
};

var winner = 5;
var ticket = 0;
var roll = function roll() {
  ticket = Math.round(Math.random() * 10);
};
var play = function play() {
  roll();
  return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
    if (ticket === winner) {
      resolve();
    } else {
      console.log("Sorry Try Again");
      reject();
    }
  });
};

retry(play).then(function () {
  console.log('winner');
});
```

However!!! The simplest fix is this

```
var winner = 5;
var ticket = 0;
var roll = function() {
  ticket = Math.round(Math.random() * 10);
}
var play = function() {
  roll();
  return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
    if (ticket === winner) {
      resolve();
    } else {
      console.log("Sorry Try Again");
      // setTimeout to avoid recursion
      setTimeout(function() {
          resolve(play());
      }, 0);
      // OR use Promise.resolve().then to asynchify the call to play so as to also avoid recusrion
      Promise.resolve().then(function() {
          resolve(play());
      });
    }
  });

}


play().then(function() {
  console.log("Winner Winner!")
});
```

instead of just calling play again, you `resolve(play())` - doing this could cause `too much recursion` as well.

To overcome the recursion problem, simply wrap the `resolve(play())` in a setTimeout **or** `Promise.resolve().then(function() { ... });` as shown in the code (use one OR the other, not both :p )

Comment: So `reject` throws an error that'll be caught within `retry`?

Comment: exactly, and retry will keep calling play until there's no rejection

Comment: I've added what is probably a simpler fix which doesn't require reject/catch at all

Comment: Whoa, this got kinda intense.

Comment: Not sure what is intense about it